# Get WMS version from QGIS layer in Python

Tags: pyqgis, wms

I need to retrieve the WMS version from a QGIS layer in Python. I can see the version in amongst the `metadata()`, but is there a better way than having to parse all of that HTML for one little value?

Comment: Why not just use an XPath expression on the source GetCapabilites document using ElementTree, something like `WMT_MS_Capabilities/@version`  if you get no response it's a version 1.3.0 service...

Comment: The result of `metadata()` is the result of GetCapabilites  in HTML format and you can also use  [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup)

Comment: Thanks, both. These are the kind of methods I was hoping to avoid as over complex, and because of extra dependencies. But if no QGIS API method exists, I guess I'll have to wade into the soup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a *hacky* way but you can avoid using BeautifulSoup by splitting the metadata (which is printed as a looong string) at `"WMS Version"` and print off the next few characters which represents the version:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
string = "<tr><td>WMS Version</td><td>"
layer.metadata().split(string)[1][:5]
```

Which for my WMS layer prints:

```
u'1.3.0'
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to isolate it more accurately by extracting only the version number `<td>version_number</td>` then I would suggest using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

layer = iface.activeLayer()
string = "<tr><td>WMS Version</td><td>(.+?)</td>"

result = re.search(string, layer.metadata())
if result:
    wms_version = result.group(1)

print wms_version
```

[image: WMS Version]

---

**Second edit:**

As [@Tom Chadwin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/36921/tom-chadwin) found out to his problem in regards to translating the WMS version from another language, replacing `"WMS Version"` with `QCoreApplication.translate("QgsWmsProvider", "WMS Version")` seems to have worked. So the edited code would be:

```
import re

layer = iface.activeLayer()
string = "<tr><td>" + QCoreApplication.translate("QgsWmsProvider", "WMS Version") + "</td><td>(.+?)</td>"

result = re.search(string, layer.metadata())
if result:
    wms_version = result.group(1)

print wms_version
```

Comment: Can we guarantee that the version string will always be 5 characters long? I suppose a second `split()` on the following tag would isolate it more reliably. Would it be `.split('</td>')[0]`?

Comment: @TomChadwin - You're probably right in that we can't guarantee if the string will be 5 characters so I've edited my post to provide an alternative method which should extract everything inside the `<td>version_number</td>` tags =)

Comment: Thanks for the fully worked example - much appreciated. It's not what I wanted to do, but since no alternative has been suggested, I've accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @TomChadwin - Most welcome, it does seem like a hassle to obtain a simple version number but hopefully there is a method to extract it directly instead of through the metadata ;)

Comment: I think if there were such a version, someone would have posted it here, and I couldn't find one in the API docs.

Comment: I've run into a problem with this solution, I think. A user's settings are not English, so will `metadata()` be translated? That would mean searching for "VERSION" would obviously fail.

Comment: @TomChadwin - Can't confirm this. If it is an issue, perhaps create a list which includes the translation of "version" in various languages and use the regular expression to iterate through this list?

Comment: Have replace `"WMS Version"` in your regex with `QCoreApplication.translate("", "WMS Version")`. We'll see if that works.

Comment: No, that doesn't work: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/396#issuecomment-276823908. I have no other ideas, other than having every transnational of "WMS Version" hard coded and checking against them all, as you suggest.

Comment: @TomChadwin - That is indeed a shame! You might have better luck asking a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and see if anyone knows of an existing method or atleast something more efficient than creating a list of the translations.

Comment: OK, it looks as though `QCoreApplication.translate("QgsWmsProvider", "WMS Version")` does the trick. Replace "WMS Version" in your code with the above.

Comment: @TomChadwin - Nice one! Hopefully that's the problem solved ;)